# How to delete SharedPreferences from selected ListView

Tags: android, json, listview, gson, sharedpreferences

I'm using GSON to store JSON into SharedPreferences, I have a method that deletes the swiped row from the ListView, How can I also delete the sharedPreferences from that swiped row ?

```
ListViewNews.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {    
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    ...    
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (event.getX() - historicX < -DELTA) {
                            ...    
                            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface. OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    newsAdapter.FunctionDeleteRowWhenSlidingLeft(position);    

                                    **ATTEMPT OF DELETION**
                                    //Delete from Database
                                    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                                    String json = sharedPrefs.getString(TAG, null);
                                    News news = gson.fromJson(json, News.class);

                                    News selItem = (News) newsAdapter.getItem(position);

                                    //read
                                    News news2 = gson.fromJson(json, News.class);
                                    System.out.println("---"+news2.getStory_id()+"---");

                                    /*
                                    This deletes everything
                                    editor.remove("HackerNews");
                                    */

                                    editor.commit();
                                    editor.apply();

                                    //read
                                    sharedPrefs.getString("json", "");
                                    System.out.println("SP"+sharedPrefs.getAll());
                                }
                            ...
```

Comment: What kind of data is your ListView made from? Is that data stored in a single JSON? Is it a possibility to overwrite the SharedPreferences key-value, or do you need to simply modify it? I think I can help, but I need to know the answer for this questions :)

Comment: @S.Czop my list view is made of GSON Strings stored in SharedPreferences, this is how they're stored:

 `news = new News(story_id, story_title, author, created_at, story_url);

 //Add from JSON
 SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
 Gson gson = new Gson();

 String json = gson.toJson(news);
 editor.putString(TAG, json);
 editor.commit();

 //read
 News news2 = gson.fromJson(json, News.class);

 //Add from SharedPreferences
 newsAdapter.add(news2);`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion/solution:

- Create an `ArrayList<News> newsList` which holds every News that will be shown in your `ListView`.
- Store `newsList` in `SharedPreferences`, and also use it to create your adapter for the `ListView`.
- To delete an element in `newsList`, get the List stored in `SharedPreferences` under a new name, such as `newsListNew`.
- Find the item in `newsListNew` with an `iterator` and remove it.
- Clear `newsList`
- Add all `newsListNew` to `newsList`
- Notify the change to the adapter, so it updates the `ListView`.
- Overwrite the `SharedPreferences`.

This is what I'm currently using for my current project. The ListView should work with a set of data, an `ArrayList` should be your choice, instead of creating a SharedPreferences storage for each of your `News`. This way, you avoid having to iterate somehow on the SharedPreferences, and instead you work with ArrayList which is something more familiar to everyone. If I had to make a draft of this, it would look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<News> newsList, newsListNew;
MyCustomAdapter adapter; //Can be an ArrayAdapter or Custom Adapter

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//Initialize the main ArrayList
 Gson gson = new Gson();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String json = prefs.getString("newsList", null);
        if (json == null) {
            newsList = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<News>>(){}.getType();
            newsList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        }

//Attach the adapter
adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, newsList)
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}


//Method for removing a News
    public void deleteNews(String id) {

Gson gson = new Gson();

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
        "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String json = prefs.getString("newsList", null);
if (json == null) {
    newsListNew = new ArrayList<>();
} else {
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<News>>(){}.getType();
    newsListNew = gson.fromJson(json, type);
}

for(Iterator<News> iterator = newsListNew.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
News news = iterator.next();
if (news.id == id) { //Look for the News element
iterator.remove(); //Remove the News from the ArrayList
break; //Include break if the Id is unique, remove it if the Id might repeat
}
}

newsList.clear(); //Empty the main ArrayList
newsList.addAll(newsListNew); //Replace the ArrayList with new info
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Update the ListView UI
//Save the newsList again into SharedPreferences by turning it into a JSON, as you normally do

}
```

It might be confusing the idea of doing .clear() and then .addAll(), but surprisingly, if you didn't include them, notifyDataSetChanged() wouldn't always work. I hope this works, feel free to ask me anything extra and I can make an edit to the answer